# Moonscript, add a function/method to an object?

Tags: moonscript

How do I do this in Moonscript?

```
function a:do_something(b)
    print(b)
end
```

Nothing I tried would compile and I didn't see anything in their documentation.

Answer (score 2):

In Lua what you wrote is syntactic sugar for the following:

```
a.do_something = function(self, b)
  print(b)
end
```

So you would do just that in MoonScript. (note the `=>` as a shorthand for adding `self` to the front of the function's argument list)

```
a.do_something = (b) =>
  print b
```

Answer (score 1):

In MoonScript you'd do:

```
a.dosomething = (self, b) ->
  print b
```

The `->` and `=>` symbols are aliases of the `function` keyword.

```
a.dosomething = (b) =>
  print b
```

Using the `=>` (Fat arrow) style as above, adds the scope, ie. `self`, to the arguments list automatically.

Comment: FYI: This appeared in the Low Quality Posts queue, probably because it is a code only answer.

Answer (score 0):

what you're looking for is `class.__base`:

```
class C
  a: (x)=> print x

C.__base.b = (y)=> @a y*2

i=C!

i\b 5
--prints 10
```